# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at ServerResponse.setHeader

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

Github : https://github.com/UJJWAL2001/Pro-Shop/tree/main/backend

I am trying to use JWT token for protecting my routes via a middleware given below

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import User from '../models/userModel.js'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]

      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')
      console.log(req.user)
      next()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(401)
      throw new Error('Not Authorized, token failed')
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Not authorized, no token found')
  }

  next()
})

export { protect }
```

I am hitting the correct route but still receiving this

```
{
    "message": "Not found - /api/users/profile",
    "stack": "Error: Not found - /api/users/profile\n    at notFound (file:///Users/ujjwalchaudhary/Desktop/proshop/backend/middleware/errorMiddleware.js:2:17)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ujjwalchaudhary/Desktop/proshop/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/Users/ujjwalchaudhary/Desktop/proshop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /Users/ujjwalchaudhary/Desktop/proshop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/Users/ujjwalchaudhary/Desktop/proshop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n    at Immediate.next (/Users/ujjwalchaudhary/Desktop/proshop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/ujjwalchaudhary/Desktop/proshop/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)\n    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)"
}
```

I checked that i am hitting api/users/profile -> `protect` -> `getUserProfile`->`app.use(notFound)`->`app.use(errorHandler)`
But the cycle should by terminated at `res.json({...})` of `getUserProfile`

You can check the routes and middlewares at my github repo mentioned above.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when using `asyncHandler()`, when you call the `next` function, it keeps executing code so below each `next()`, my solution was to put return,
for example, in your protect middleware after the `next()`.

```js
try {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

    req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')
    console.log(req.user)
    next()
    return;    // here
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Not Authorized, token failed')
}
```

And do it in the controllers too, when you use `res.json` or `res.send` do it with a return like

```js
return res.json({message: 'message'})
```

`asyncHandler` won't let you `return res.json`, so I think putting a return on the next line is one way to fix it.